# Is there a way to call update() without changing the priority on the record?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am updating a database location like this:

```
 db.child(itemId).update(rec);
```

However, when I make this call it is deleting or nulling the current priority of the record. For this particular update call I do not want to change the current priority of the record in the db. Is this possible?

Example (this nulls the current priority already at the node):

```
        var rec = {}; 
        rec[itemKey] = false;

        db.child(userId).update(rec);
```

Example (this also nulls the current priority already at the node)

```
        db.child(userId).child(itemKey).set(false);
```

The JSON Structure is a list of user ids with either a true or false. Very simple structure.

Comment: Calling `update()` on a note does not necessarily change the priority of that node. If you're having a problem with that, share the [minimal code+JSON (both as text, no screenshots please) that are needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Working example: http://jsbin.com/kexano/edit?html,js,console

Comment: example of what I am doing added

Comment: Calling `set()` will indeed clear the existing priority. Calling `update()` doesn't as my jsbin shows. If that doesn't work for you, try reproducing it in a jsbin just like I did.